# Pipe with ls, grep and wc

Tags: unix

Can anyone tell me about the output/purpose of this command?

`ls -l | grep gopal | wc -l`

Comment: homework? context of question?

Answer (score 3):

It will show the number of files in the current directory which contain the string "gopal" in their name.

Or at least it *would*, if it had been written correctly...

Comment: What's wrong with it? Seems fine to me

Comment: Or possibly files owned by user/group "gopal"

Comment: good point, so ls -1 would probably be better than ls -l

Comment: @James: it wasn't fine when first posted.